# Is it possible to show top level functions in the folders and file list in the explorer in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know you can see the functions in the **Outline** section.

My question is, in the explorer there is a files/folder tree. For files, is it possible to show the top level functions nested under the file? So I can expand a folder to find a file, then expand a file to see the top level functions in it?